# How to use ANY on list, created from integer's array?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, any

How do I check that an array or list as shown below contains a given value using either LINQ's Contains() or Any() functions?

here is my Code:

```
int[] array3 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
List<int> tyest = array3.ToList<int>();
if (tyest.Any(2)) { 

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Any` accepts a `Func<T, bool>` as a parameter when executed on In-Memory collections  :

```
if(array3.Any(x=> x == 2))
```

Or

```
if(tyest.Any(x=> x == 2))
```

Notes:

- You don't need to convert to a List to use `Any`, it works on any `IEnumerable<T>` (This includes generic arrays and generic lists) .

To Understand a lambda:

```
(x) => x == 2
```

is equivalent to:

```
private bool filterFunction(int x)
{
   return x == 2;
}
```

The `Any` Linq extension method loops through all the elements of an `IEnumerable` and executes the lambda function on each element, if it finds one element that returns true when executing this function, then the `Any` returns true, else it returns false;

Comment: I think your problem may be that you answered more than was asked. I try to deliberately keep my answers short and to the point only answering what was asked as it helps the asker get their solution and move on faster. Also lots of edits often results in many down votes I have seen

Comment: @War Is this a reason to down-vote a correct answer ?

Comment: @ElieSaad Because converting to list is useless in his case. This is not a reason to down-vote the correct answer that explains everything to the use. Also included in the answer that `Any` works on both `List<T>` and Arrays.

Comment: Just giving you my opinion as to why someone may have down voted you ... as you asked.

Comment: @ElieSaad That is already mentioned in my answer, check the notes section. + It is very obvious that the user doesn't know how to use lambdas when he wrote `.Any(2)` .. That's why I explained this section to him. So if I added more info to my answer because the use clearly didn't understand lambdas , then you down-vote it ? This is ridiculous.

Comment: @War So this is long answer ? You've got to be kidding me. This just explains *How* and on *What* types you can use `Any`. Secondly, it explains Lambdas because it is clear when the OP wrote `.Any(2)` that he doesn't know much about that topic!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120865/discussion-between-war-and-user3185569).

Answer (score 6):

Using any requires an expression that it can check against each element in the given array, try this instead ...

```
if (tyest.Any(i => i == 2)) { 

}
```

.. this works by running the expression inside the Any() against each element until it finds one that results in the "i == 2" being true.